# How to install the gtk library for Haskell in OS X?

Tags: haskell, gtk

I'm having trouble installing gtk2 for Haskell on OS X with cabal. I am using [this guide](https://wiki.haskell.org/Gtk2Hs/Installation).

Forgive my noobness, but my problems to understand starts with the following line:

> Unpack the bundle to a path that does not have spaces in it, and add the /bin directory created by unpacking to your %PATH%.

So &PATH% is where my installed packages lie right? I know that folder, but what does it mean to "add the /bin directory created by unpacking" to this folder? When I download gtk [from here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk) and unzip there isnt any folder anywhere called "/bin" or "bin". There is one directory bin in my %PATH% that contains some executables though? But there is not bin directory created form unzipping for example gtk-0.14.5.tar.gz?!

Obviously I am doing something wrong, because when I continue the guide I check and get:

```
gtk-0.14.5 Admin$ pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0
Package gtk+-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-2.0' found

If you see some compiler flags that contain the path into which you have installed the binary bundle, you are okay.
```

Umm what? Can someone explain this like I'm five? What is a compile flag, what is a binary bundle? It's like these guides assume that you already know what you are doing.

Very well, I continue and try to install the build tools for gtk by typing:

```
cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools
```

First it complains I don't have something called "alex" and then that I don't have something called "happy". Wtf what are those? Whatever, I install those as well, even though I do not understand what I am doing. FINALLY I am able to install the build tools.

So now only remains the actual gtk right, should be simple enough. I type:

```
cabal install gtk
```

But no.  It gives me the following error message:

```
cabal install gtk.cabal
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
next goal: gtk (user goal)
rejecting: gtk-0.14.6 (constraint from user target requires ==0.14.5)
rejecting: gtk-0.14.5 (conflict: requires pkg-config package gtk+-2.0-any, not
found in the pkg-config database)
rejecting: gtk-0.14.4, gtk-0.14.3, gtk-0.14.2, gtk-0.13.9, gtk-0.13.8.1,
gtk-0.13.8, gtk-0.13.7, gtk-0.13.6, gtk-0.13.4, gtk-0.13.3, gtk-0.13.2,
gtk-0.13.1, gtk-0.13.0.3, gtk-0.13.0.2, gtk-0.13.0.1, gtk-0.13.0.0,
gtk-0.12.5.7, gtk-0.12.5.6, gtk-0.12.5.5, gtk-0.12.5.4, gtk-0.12.5.3,
gtk-0.12.5.2, gtk-0.12.5.1, gtk-0.12.5.0, gtk-0.12.4, gtk-0.12.3.1,
gtk-0.12.3, gtk-0.12.2, gtk-0.12.1, gtk-0.12.0, gtk-0.11.2, gtk-0.11.1,
gtk-0.11.0 (constraint from user target requires ==0.14.5)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

WHAT? What am I even looking at? Excuse me but how is it *this hard* to simply install a library for Haskell? Can anyone help? I spend several days now trying to install Haskell libraries to be able to actually program something, but I reiterate, how is it that it is this hard to simply install a simple library? Am I missing something? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You downloaded the Haskell gtk package, but the docs are telling you you need the c gtk, upon which the Haskell package called `gtk` depends. `alex` and `happy` are the standard lexer/parser tools for Haskell (cabal install alex happy). %PATH% is an environment variable, nothing to do really with 'installed packages'. These guides don't assume you know anything (hence 'guide') but they do assume if you know nothing about `pkg-config` then you will read the `pkg-config` documentation to learn about it. ...

Comment: The section of the guide you are following is for Windows (clearly, since %PATH% is actually called $PATH on *nix). Finally, `cabal install gtk` fails for a reason entirely unrelated to any of the other things which didn't work - it doesn't even get to the step where it checks for that the C gtk library is installed and available. Because there are so many misunderstandings here, very few to do with Haskell, and all caused mainly by not reading the docs, I'm voting to close.

Comment: [1/2] (Since I don't use OS X, I will post this as a long comment, and leave the answers for folks in a better position to offer advice.) (1) There is [a separate Mac page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Gtk2Hs/Mac). There are more up-to-date instructions in the [readme at GitHub](https://github.com/gtk2hs/gtk2hs), but I don't know if they apply to your OS X version. (2) I don't know what in your Haskell environment is making *cabal* pick precisely the 0.14.5 version of *gtk*, but...

Comment: [2/2] ... the error mentioning pkgconfig is probably related to the fact that, as user2407038 notes, you didn't install the GTK C library yet. (3) "Excuse me but how is it this *hard* to simply install a library for Haskell?" -- In most cases it isn't. *gtk* is far more annoying to install than the norm, specially if you aren't on Linux, as it depends on a complicated non-Haskell library (the C GTK) and the bindings have a lot of moving parts.

Comment: The thing is, I am even able to install alex, happy, glib, even the build tools all using cabal. But when I type "cabal install gtk" I get Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
next goal: gtk (user goal)
rejecting: gtk-0.14.6, gtk-0.14.5, gtk-0.14.4, gtk-0.14.3, gtk-0.14.2,
gtk-0.13.9, gtk-0.13.8.1, gtk-0.13.8, gtk-0.13.7, gtk-0.13.6, gtk-0.13.4..etc
(conflict: requires pkg-config package gtk+-2.0-any,
not found in the pkg-config database)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.

Comment: The error tells you *exaclty* what is wrong - "conflict: requires pkg-config package gtk+-2.0-any, not found in the pkg-config database". Why would you expect latter steps of the installation to every succeed when the former steps haven't been completed?

Comment: This is where I am getting at, how do I solve "conflict: requires pkg-config package gtk+-2.0-any, not found in the pkg-config database"? I have no idea where I could find a pk-config package for gtk+ much less how to put it in an "pkg-config database"?

Comment: I started writing an answer, but I just couldn't do it. There's so much indignation in your post that I couldn't keep my own response professional. In short, you are following the instructions for installing on a completely different OS than the one you have. Try again with the right instructions; and if you ask another question based on those, I encourage you to stick to the technical details and skip the whining.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem on Ubuntu with:

```
sudo apt install libgtk2.0-dev
```

Maybe if you install libgtk2.0-dev on OS X (with brew maybe) you will be able to install gtk with cabal.